# SAP JCo3 source files

Tags: java, jco

In my previous post I have mentioned that my `sapjco3.jar` is not getting recognized in Eclipse. I tried various suggestions. But nothing works in Eclipse.

So I am thinking of getting the SAP JCo3 source files and including it in my project along with my code.

So can any one tell me, is it available anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: I have answered to one of your posts, maybe this works for you, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901220/1592796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAP JCo is a proprietary closed-source library. Unless you work for SAP, you won't get the source files - and you're not allowed to include the source or binary form of JCo anyway.