# SAP JBOSS issues with jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jco

I am trying to connect my J2EE application with SAP software using ABAP function calls. When I run it as a single class in Eclipse with hot coded values, it works fine. When I try to run it in JBoss server, where I am getting some values from my front end and passing it to my Java class which is the same class I referred before, it shows this following exception

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/JCoException
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
>   at org.jboss.aop.ClassContainer.createMethodMap(ClassContainer.java:182)
>
>   
>     09:35:42,326 INFO  [EARDeployer] Started J2EE application:
>                     file:/F:/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/MPCS.ear
>     09:35:42,326 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:
>
>     --- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
>     ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,module=MPCS.jar
>      State: FAILED
>      Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/JCoException
>
>     --- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
>     ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,module=MPCS.jar
>     State: FAILED
>     Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/JCoException
> ```

I have my `sapjco3.jar` in `F:/jar` where I also have `ejb3-persistence.jar`, `jboss-ejb3x.jar`, etc. and they are properly recognized. I have added the jar in build path also. But nothing helps.

Comment: Have you installed the correct version of the native library as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the NoClassDefFoundError in JBoss EAP 6.1 when using classes from sapjco3.jar in an EJB (annotated with @Singleton and @Startup).
Besides that I also received an error saying that the native library was already loaded in another classloader when republishing to EAP or restarting the deployed module.

My solution to both problems was to include sapjco3.jar as a global JBoss module.

### Step 1

I created the following structure inside EAPS's \modules folder:

```
com
--> sap
    --> conn
        --> jco
            --> main
                --> module.xml
                --> sapjco3.jar
```

The contents of **module.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.sap.conn.jco">
   <resources>
      <resource-root path="sapjco3.jar"/>
   </resources>
</module>
```

### Step 2

Adding the module as a global module in **standalone.xml**:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
   ... 
   <global-modules>
       <module name="com.sap.conn.jco" />
   </global-modules>
   ...
</subsystem>
```

### Step 3

Create or edit file **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** inside EJB projects META-INF to contain the module.
My file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="com.sap.conn.jco" export="TRUE" />
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

### Step 4

Configure Maven dependency as scope **provided**, so that we can work with sapjco3.jar inside the workspace but not have it inside the deployment.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
   <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.10</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That is what I recall so far to make it work, maybe this is helpful for you or anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that, could be necessary to add the dependency to the javax.api if are you using a newer version of sapjco3. This dependency is necessary to load the crypto library from Java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.sap.conn.jco">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sapjco3.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```